# Wekas Wrapper feature selector equivalent in Scikit-learn

Tags: scikit-learn, feature-selection

Is there any weka-style wrapper equivalent in scikit learn?

In Weka I do feature selection using WrapperSubsetEval with wrapping Naive Bayes. I set BestFirst as a search method and features selected this way give me very good accuracy.

When I do

```
mod = MultinomialNB().fit(x, y)
selector = SelectFromModel(mod, prefit=True)
x = selector.transform(x)
```

It chooses features that give me very bad accuracy. 
Is it not the same? 
MultinomialNB in scikit gives me the same results as Multinomial NB in weka. But feature selection works really bad.